# JQuery Decimals not adding

Tags: jquery

I have an array of prices, I want to add a price to them.

```
var priceTotal = '1250.00';
for (var p = 0; p < price.length; p++) {
            priceTotal = parseFloat(priceTotal).toFixed(2) + parseFloat(price[p]).toFixed(2);
            alert(priceTotal);
 }
```

The one value in the array im testing is 30.00, so the answer I end up with is 1250.0030

I need 1280.00.

I thought I was doing it correctly with parseFloat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becaue [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string, so you are doing string concatenation.

```js
var price = ['30.00']
var priceTotal = '1250.00';
for (var p = 0; p < price.length; p++) {
  priceTotal = (+priceTotal + +price[p]).toFixed(2);
}
alert(priceTotal);
```

or call the [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) at the end

```js
var price = ['30.00']
var priceTotal = +'1250.00'; //or just 1250.00;
for (var p = 0; p < price.length; p++) {
  priceTotal = priceTotal + +price[p];
}
priceTotal = priceTotal.toFixed(2)
alert(priceTotal);
```